# How do I clear an element before rendering?

Tags: lit-html

I have inherited an older project using jquery.

I am modernising the code.

In particular this `$(selector).html("<h1>lol</h1>");` which as far as I understand is a full replacement of the selectors content.

I always end up with an error if I try to render to a cleared element.

This code:

```js
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;

// trying to replace jquery $(selector).html("<h1>lol</h1>");

appDiv.innerHTML = '';
render(html`<h1>lol</h1>`, appDiv);

appDiv.innerHTML = '';
render(html`<h1>lol</h1>`, appDiv);
```

Or see [my stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-3hmr8d?file=index.ts)

I always get the following error:

**Error in lit-html.js (93:55)
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'insertBefore')**

Do you know what I am missing?

Thanks!

Note: This is a duplicate of my question (and based on a suggested technique) from a closed [Lit Github Issue](https://github.com/lit/lit/issues/2189)

Note: Maybe I am talking rubbish. I can't find a clear answer if `render` REPLACES content or APPENDS content. A concrete answer on that would be fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lit v1 will clear the container before rendering the first time. Lit v2 will not.

Only clear the existing container content once before using `render`. After that render will correctly update content from previous `render` calls.

```js
const appDiv: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('app');
appDiv.innerHTML = `<h1>TypeScript Starter</h1>`;

// trying to replace jquery $(selector).html("<h1>lol</h1>");

appDiv.innerHTML = '';
render(html`<h1>lol</h1>`, appDiv);

render(html`<h1>lol2</h1>`, appDiv);
```

Comment: Thank you abraham, I really appreciate the clarification.